# how to pad "x" to the end of a string of fixed length

Tags: sql, sql-server

This code:

```
select right('XXXXXXXXXXX' + 'BARCGB22', 11)
```

Results in: "XXXBARCGB22"

But I need the reversed and I'm having a hard time doing it. It needs to be:

"BARCGB22XXX"

Can anyone give me a quick hand?

Thanks

Comment: How about `select left('BARCGB22'+'XXXXXXXXXXX', 11)`.

Comment: @Shawn yes, and that's an actual answer. You should write it as such

Comment: thanks Shawn. I dont know why I was getting an error when doing what you did. post it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming `BARCGB22` will be coming from a variable. I'd use `SELECT left(coalesce(myvar,'')+'XXXXXXXXXXX', 11)`. `NULL' kinda has a special meaning and it behaves a bit different from a normal variable.

**EDIT:**

Or '...isNull(myvar,'')...`.`isNull()`and`coalesce()`do just about the same thing, but`isNull`is T-SQL while`coalesce` is more generic.